# How can I fix SQL ERROR on GROUP BY? I am trying to AVG a summary stat

Tags: sql, average

I'm new to SQL and need serious help understanding how to express what I'd like the data to show.

This is the Data:

table: `naap`

columns: `avg_score_4`, `avg_score_8`, `avg_loss_4`, `avg_loss_8`, `id`, `city`, `year`

I am trying to write a query that returns summary statistics by averaging for `avg_score_4` according to `city`. After that I want to sort the results alphabetically by city name. However, I have been running into trouble getting the correct function to express any of this.

So far this is the last formula (out of trying so many combinations) i've been working on.

```sql
SELECT city, AVG (avg_score_4)
FROM naap,
ORDER BY city AS s DESC;
```

I've tried `WHERE` and also `GROUP BY` but the same error keeps showing after "FROM naap,"
Please help! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got at least one issue, which is the out-of-place comma after `FROM naap,`.

This should work for you:

```
SELECT city, AVG(avg_score_4) As Score4Average
FROM naap
GROUP BY city
ORDER by city
```

Comment: Ken, this absolutely worked! From all the sequences I've tried I see that yes, the comma was one of the problems. The other was my AS. I shortened the AS to 'a' (though I wonder if this adds or takes away from the results. I appreciate your response. This has clarified the mistakes I kept on making.